# how to run ffmpeg terminal (mac) command in java

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg

I use FFmpeg codec in order to do the video conversion. This time I have a huge number of videos, so I am trying to do the video conversion automatically.

I am trying to do so like this in java.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -r 25 -pixel_format yuv422p -i input.yuv -vf yadif  output.yuv");
```

But my java program returns the following error:

```
Cannot run program "ffmpeg": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Does anyone has any clue how I can do it in java?

Answer (score 0):

The OS tells you, that the command "ffmpeg" is not found at the location where you are executing it (and obviously, it is not part of the PATH environment variable). Hence, this is error is unrelated to Java.

Comment: Thanks all, i found a batch program to solve this. 
Here you go: <br>`#!/bin/bash
for name in *.yuv ; do 
    ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -r 25 -pixel_format yuv422p -i $name -vf yadif  ${name%.*}_deInt.yuv
done`<br>

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:"+File.separatorChar+"....."+File.separatorChar+"ffmpeg -video_size 1920x1080 -r 25 -pixel_format yuv422p -i input.yuv -vf yadif  output.yuv");
```

to specify where ffmpeg is.

Comment: Why would you delete a good answer when someone merely asks you whether you can improve it? (Note there wasn't any voting on your answer!!)  http://stackoverflow.com/a/36705893/981744